# How to use Google Recaptcha v3 with a Custom Image Submit Button?

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I'm wondering if it's possible to use recaptcha V3 with an image as the submission button. When I use this code, recaptcha loads just fine and submits a token:

```
<form id="test" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[PublicKey]" data-callback='onSubmit' data-action='submit' type="submit" value="Submit me!" />
</form>
<script>function onSubmit(token){document.getElementById("test").submit();}</script>
```

However, recaptcha won't load and doesn't generate a token when using an image type input like this:

```
<form id="test" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[PublicKey]" data-callback='onSubmit' data-action='submit' type="image" src="myButton.png" />
</form>
<script>function onSubmit(token){document.getElementById("test").submit();}</script>
```

I'm guessing that the button type is an issue. But is there a way around that, because I'd love to have a custom image button instead of a system button. Help? Thanks all!